# TFS Work Item<->Build association best practices

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-workitem

We recently adopted the concept of feature branches in one of our bigger projects, to segregate work on different aspects of the product that can be completed independently of each other.

For each so-called feature, we are creating the following:

- a branch from 'main', aptly named after what the feature is supposed to be
- a new team in the project portal, containing the people that will work on the feature
- a build definition to validate check-ins against the source on the branch

The main point I would like to see discussed here is about the build definition. Currently, each one of them is set to gated checkins.

The question then, is: what is the best practice on associating work items to a build?

In our case, these feature branches are supposed to be disposable: we would like to be able to delete these builds/branches/teams later on when the feature is complete, but still be able to track them throughout the product lifecycle.

If I associate work items with these temporary builds, I'll lose tracking capability later on when the feature implementation ends. At the same time, I just found out that [gated checkins always associate work items, regardless of what is configured in the build definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973786/gated-check-in-always-associates-work-items-with-build).

Would it be feasible to disable work item integration with the feature branches (in this case also converting them from gated to continuous integration) and enable it in the main build, so that these features can be tracked in the main product line? Or maybe this should be only enabled for Release build definitions, so that we can find out what was integrated on a certain release? For those of you who follow the sprint/feature concept, how do you handle this situation? Do you also have a build for each branch?

**Update:**

I just found something similar (but not exactly like what I wanted) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536323/how-to-determine-the-work-items-fixed-in-a-particular-tfs-build-when-using-branc). The answer there lead me to [a plugin that automatically associates work items on merge checkins](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2011/05/17/automatically-merging-work-items-in-tfs-2010.aspx). This should offer great traceability on it's own, so I think I'll give it a shot.

Would still like to hear what your thoughts are in regards to the builds in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching this wrong IMO.  You shouldn't be worrying about associating Builds and WI's, but rather associating Changesets and WI's.  When your developers check-in changes in the feature branch you should ensure that they are linking them to the relevant WI(s).  You can even enforce this via a Check-In Policy.

Now if you ever want to inspect that feature in the future to see all the changes associated with it, you can by inspecting the Feature WI, and looking at all linked Changesets.  Even if you delete the branch all the Changesets are still available.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. But then how do I find out which features were integrated in a given build? Also yes, we are actually using the Work Item policy right now, so this [associating changesets to work items] is already covered.

Comment: For getting the build report specifically to give you a list of WI's that are integrated in that build, I'd suggest you use Colin's custom TFS Build activity that does that (in conjunction with Jakob's that associated the Merge Changeset with the WI's).  http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/2013/02/custom-build-task-include-merged.html